# Can Mongoose populate the field directly instead of nesting in object?

Tags: mongoose

```
const personSchema = Schema({
  name: String,
  age: Number,
});

const storySchema = Schema({
  author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' },
  title: String,
});
```

In the example it outputs:

```
{
  author: {
    name: 'Ken',
    age:  30,
  },
  title: '...',
}
```

My expected result is:

```
{
  authorName: 'Ken',
  authorAge: 30,
  title: '...',
}
```

Is there any way to do that?
I know it can handle after I get the list, but I want to know if I need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is possible, using the aggregate function and a trick to satisfy the group operator retrieving the first occurrence of any object. This query do the work:

```
db.person.aggregate(
  [
    {$group:
       { _id:'$_id',
         authorName: {$first:'$author.name'},
         authorAge:{$first:'$author.age'},
         title:{$first:'$title'}
        }
     }
   ],{cursor:{}})
```

So, that's the result:

```
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5c4af0df17d4bb03faf6e9fe"),
    "authorName": "Julie",
    "authorAge": 40,
    "title": "..."
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5c4ae86417d4bb03faf6e9fd"),
    "authorName": "Ken",
    "authorAge": 30,
    "title": "..."
  }
```

Comment: It does't work, `authorName` and `authorAge` get null. `author` of the story model is not a real object, it's an ObjectId ref to the person model. So I think it can't get it's property before populate.
My code:
`Story.aggregate(
  [
    {$group:
       { _id:'$_id',
         authorName: {$first:'$author.name'},
         authorAge:{$first:'$author.age'},
         title:{$first:'$title'}
        }
     }
   ])`

Comment: I use lookup and unwind to achieve. Thank you!